# How to initialize a variable in a Service class

Tags: java, spring, service

I have a Spring Service class and I want to put a static variable in it that will be initialized with values once when the Service is created by Spring by Autowired.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements IService {

   public static HashMap<String,String> settings = new HashMap<String,String>();

   public MyServiceImpl() {
      settings.put("key1","value1");
      settings.put("key2","value2");
   }
```

And then when I Autowired that Service the variable will be initialized just once.
Is there any solution how to achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`@PostConstruct`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-combined-effects):

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    //fill values into map here
}
```

Comment: import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

Answer (score 0):

Spring Beans' default scope is singleton, so you can use constructor and `@PostConstruct` as well as `InitializingBean` interfaces or static initializer.
Some suggestion: dont use static variable if not necessary, it is not a good practice, easy to create memory leak etc. If you try to get the map before spring container initialize the bean, it will be empty and other problems can occure.